# Why is map_blocks reshaping my array and how can I control this?

Tags: python, arrays, dask

I want to use dask for a non-dask-aware function ([`pyproj.Geod.inv`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/dev/api/geod.html#pyproj.Geod.inv)), which I can do with `dask.array.map_blocks`.  The latter expects a function that returns an `ndarray`, but `pyproj.Geod.inv` returns a tuple of ndarrays, so I'm concatenating the resulting ndarrays in a wrapper function that I then pass to `dask.array.map_blocks`.  But the resulting shape is different from what I expect.  The following example illustrate the problem (of course, here `f` could take dask arrays directly, but `pyproj.Geod.inv` cannot):

```py
import dask.array

def f(x, y):
    return (x+y, x*y)

def wrap(x, y):
    return dask.array.dstack(f(x, y))

x = dask.array.arange(2784, chunks=32)
y = dask.array.arange(2784, chunks=32)
(xc, yc) = dask.array.meshgrid(x, y)
mp = dask.array.map_blocks(wrap, xc, yc, dtype="f4", chunks=(32, 32, 2))
print(mp, mp.shape, mp.compute().shape)
```

I was expecting to get an array back with shape (2784, 2784, 2).  However, the output of this script is:

```
dask.array<wrap, shape=(32, 2784, 174), dtype=float32, chunksize=(32, 32, 2), chunktype=numpy.ndarray> (32, 2784, 174) (32, 2784, 174)
```

What is going on here?  The function `f` is being called with arrays of size `(32, 32)`.  The function `wrap` then produces arrays of `(32, 32, 2)`.  Those get passed back to dask.  But rather than reshaping this to `(2784, 2784, 2)`, it gets reshaped into `(32, 2784, 174)`.  Why is this happening and how can I get dask to produce an array with the intended shape in the first place?  Of course, I could reshape the resulting array, but that would be treating the symptom rather than the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.map_blocks):

> If the function changes the dimension of the blocks you must specify the created or destroyed dimensions.

The function in the example changes the dimension of the blocks.  In the question, one should replace

```py
mp = dask.array.map_blocks(wrap, xc, yc, dtype="f4", chunks=(32, 32, 2))
```

by

```py
mp = dask.array.map_blocks(wrap, xc, yc, dtype="f4", chunks=(32, 32, 2), new_axis=2)
```

then the example script will result in

```
dask.array<wrap, shape=(2784, 2784, 2), dtype=float32, chunksize=(32, 32, 2), chunktype=numpy.ndarray> (2784, 2784, 2) (2784, 2784, 2)
```

i.e. the shape of the dask array is as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting into the rest of your procedure, you should ensure that the function you pass to `map_blocks` receives and should return a *numpy* array, on in this case two arrays:

```
def wrap(x, y):
    return np.dstack(f(x, y))
```

Comment: I suppose you're right.  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to change the resulting array.